# Orchard - Hide "Set as home page" checkbox on admin side

Tags: orchardcms

is it possible to somehow hide "Set as home page" checkbox when adding new content in Orchard (without removing Autoroute part)?

Thank you,

Jakub

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Autoroute exposes a permission "Set Home Page". You can revoke this permission for user roles whom you don't want to show the checkbox.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. Is it possible to hide it for admin as well?

Comment: You could revoke that permission from the Admin role, but the site owner always has all permissions.

Comment: Go to Users > Roles, certain roles have the permission, such as Editor. I unchecked it there