# Add the Autoroute Part without letting users promote the content as the home page

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

Can we add the Autoroute part to a Content Type while also preventing users from being able "to promote this content as the home page?"

Comment: Yes you can. The 'Set as homepage' is only available for those who have the proper rights, like the admin.

Comment: Checkout this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918425/orchard-hide-set-as-home-page-checkbox-on-admin-side?rq=1

Comment: @user3153169 Please put this as answer not comment or mark as duplicate.